# Regular expression to allow only one special character?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am trying to add validation for names that allow apostrophe, dash and period only once in   the input.

I tried using the below expression:

```
name= /^[a-zA-Z-,]+(\-\.\'\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/
```

But the values are accepting only one character after the alphabets.
How to specify the characters to allow only once in the regular expression.
What is the mistake in my expression?

EDIT:

```
^[-'.a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\-\.\'\s|]{0,25}$
```

But this allows the special characters to allow multiple times.

Comment: The question has been tagged C#, but you seem to be using javascript syntax? Also, please post example text.

Comment: Are all special character optional?

Comment: `-` in character class should be escaped or in the start/end inside `[...]`

Comment: Pretty silly requirements...

Comment: Poor Anne-Marie Smith-Bloggs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to add validation for names that allow apostrophe, dash and period only once in the input.

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z,]*['.-][a-zA-Z,]*$)[a-zA-Z,'.-]+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tH9xS1/1)

Here `(?=.*?['.-][^'.-]*$)` is a lookahead that makes sure to allow only one of apostrophe OR dash OR period in the input.

Comment: Why would you not just use the lookahead on its own, replacing the `.` and the `[^'.-]` with `[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: @Rawling: Sure `[^'.-]` can be replaced with `[a-zA-Z,]` also.

Comment: In fact without doing so this is broken because the `.*` allows multiple special characters despite the `?`.

Comment: It's still inefficient. The lookahead could be used as the entire expression.

Comment: @Rawling: What is your suggested regex for this lookahead?

Comment: Remove the `(?=` and the `)[a-zA-Z,'.-]+$`. It's akin to `^(?=xyz$)[xyz]+$`.

Comment: Just `^[a-zA-Z,]*['.-][a-zA-Z,]*$` will always force single special character, I think OP wants one or none.

Comment: What? Your lookahead also forces a special character.

Comment: Yes true. But this lookahead can be converted to `^(?!([a-zA-Z,]*['.-]){2})[a-zA-Z,'.-]+$` for that purpose. Sorry I couldn't respond earler as I was away from my computer.

Answer (score -1):

Use optional quantifier `?`:

```
^[a-zA-Z-,]*[-.'\sÀ-ÿ|]?[a-zA-Z-,]*$
```

Here is an [UPDATED regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dW7jJ0/2)!